# How to renew self signed SSL in IIS for local website

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012, iis, ssl-certificate

Our self-signed SSL certificate will run out of time within 6 days. How do we renew this?
We use this on IIS and it's only for internal network. Any tips? Do we have to renew? Our employees already added it as *trusted* to their browsers though.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx tells you how.  If you want the service to continue to operate over TLS/SSL then you will need to renew.  Once you've renewed you'll need to distribute the certificate to all your employees' devices again. As for tips - stand up a small internal CA to save this happening again?

Comment: Do you mean after 6 days we won't be able to use the website over SSL and it must be renewed?

Comment: You'll get a warning that the certificate is invalid (which it is, as it has expired).  The details depends on which browser your employees use.